# ConstraintLayout draws outside DialogFragment boundaries

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-dialogfragment

I want to create a dialog with round corners using ConstraintLayout, DialogFragment and a custom background.

The dialog must have a scroll area at the top and a custom button at the bottom. The dialog should resize in height based on the size of the scroll view.
I tried on Android 6 and Android 9 but the issue with the above combination is present on both platforms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/animated_vector_cross"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:textColor="@color/sweet_dialog_bg_color_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_XXLarge_Land"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_accept_bt_ripple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_ok"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView5"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bt_ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fs_XLarge_Land" />
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" /> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that if the text that I put inside the scroll view is big the bottom button will be pushed outside of the dialog.

[With little text the dialog shrinks but the bottom button is correctly displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9s4F.png)

[With big text the button is pushed outside.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsNPE.png)

What settings do I miss?

Comment: try setting ScrollView height as 0dp

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by wrapping the ConstraintLayout with a LinearLayout and using wrap_content parameters.